# How to configure bluebooth dialing behavoir?

Tags: bluetooth, calls

I connect a Bluetooth earpiece to my Android phone to allow me to receive calls when driving. By accident, I discovered that if I quickly press the button on my earpiece twice, the phone will automatically re-dials the last *outgoing* call, which is pretty annoying.

1. Is this a function of the Bluetooth earpiece, or a function of the phone?
2. Assuming that it is a function of the phone, how can I configure it so that it re-dials the last call, irrespective of whether it is incoming or outgoing?
3. I cannot find this function described anywhere in the manuals that come with either the Bluetooth earpiece or the phone. Where can I find more hidden functions where clicking the earpiece button at a predetermined pattern will make the phone do something?

My phone is a Asus Zenfone if it matters.

Comment: It must be the feature of that bluetooth earphone